# OpenVPN Internet Sharing OSX

Tags: mac, openvpn

I have an OSX Mac mini running with OpenVPN. The basic setup works fine. Using the Mac mini I can easily connect via my own OpenVPN setup on AWS/EC2.

Now I want to share this (cable-Ethernet) internet to Wifi. This works fine using Apples built in Internet Sharing.
But, it doesn't share my OpenVPN connection, it only shares my non VPN connection.

I appreciate this could be setup somehow in the routing tables for Apples built in Internet Sharing. I have googled for a few days to no avail. Does anyone have a working setup for this and could point me in the correct direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any idea over it. I also want to share OpenVPN connection through WIFI internet sharing from my macOS.

Comment: I tried and found some OpenVPN hacks, which were all over-complicated. I settled for a simpler solution as I am running VPN on my machine in the cloud. I am running on an L2TP setup which I easily setup on AWS. So now I'm using standard OSX Sharing (of the L2TP connection). Also bought a 1USD app which keeps L2TP alive. Let me know if you would like full setup described in an answer.